# Razorengine "Unable to compile template. Check the Errors list for details."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, templating

I'm using "Razorengine" to generate the emailbody from a cshtml template.
When running the application in debug mode (VS 2010) all is working well.
The template is rendered well and all data from the model is inserted as wanted.

But when I publish the app. to my  local IIS server (win 7 pro) I get the error "unable to compile ..."
When I publish to a live IIS server (online hoster) I get another error ("The type initializer for 'RazorEngine.Razor' threw an exception.")

cshtml template starts with

```
@inherits "RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase <Ebits.EnrolmentLCMT.Core.boekingBeheer.resumeBoekingObject>
```

it contains stylesheets, html and razor tags refering to the Model

This I call in my code:

```
resumeBoekingObject resumeBoeking = boekingBeheer.getBoekingResume(boeking, taal);
string mailBodyTemplate = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../htmlPages/confirmMailTemplate.cshtml"));
string mailBodyTekst = Razor.Parse<resumeBoekingObject>(mailBodyTemplate, resumeBoeking);
```

!! I'm sure the template is read well because I've used it as bodytekst in my mail.

Any ideas anybody.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your live IIS server, you likely are missing a MVC3 DLL in your deploy (my guess is  System.Web.Razor.dll). Check the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) for the presence of the file it lists in the un-posted portion of your error, and check your BIN directory for the presence of the missing file.

I ran into a similar problem tonight and found relevant info here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx